# Coupled non-linear PDE analytical solution to verify numerical solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, approximation, finite-differences

as part of a computational module we were given the following coupled PDEs and solved them numerically using finite difference methods:

[image]

I got the following graphs representing the numerical solution for 11 different times:

[image]

Is there an analytic solution to this system that I could compare my answer to?

Comment: This is highly unlikely. That's why MMS, the method of manufactured solutions, was invented. Construct some functions that look close to what you think the solutions should look like, compute their residual under the PDE and put it as time-depending forcing term on the right side. Then these invented solutions are the exact solutions that you can compare the numerical solutions against. Note that the exact MoL solution (fixed space grid) will be different from the exact PDE solution, the error according to the order of the space discretization.

Comment: I agree with Lutz Lehmann's comment. Moreover, event if it was possible to analitically solve the PDEs system you could not compare with numerical results if no boundary condition is specified.